# How to get random word2vec vector for unknow word?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I train word2vec on train data, but there are some words from test data not in the train data, so how can I produce the word vector that match the data distribution or number range like original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the list of non-frequent words in your vocabulary and average them to get an approximate word vector for unknown word.

OR

Let's say your target unknown word is `w` and its within the context `c-2 c-1 w c1 c2` where `c-2`, `c-1`, `c1` and `c2` are the context words. You could take the average of embedding of all the context words as a good approximation for the unknown word.